# How to share my Alexa smart home skill with a friend

Tags: share, alexa-skills-kit

I have developed a smart home Alexa skill with a custom lambda implementation. I want to share the link to this skill to a few friends and get their feedback. I know I can do this in a few ways:

(1) Publish it on Amazon. (My skill is in beta stage, so not yet ready to face the world).

(2) Add all the friends as collaborators in my Alexa Developer account. (There are inquisitive teens in the group).

(3) Develop the skill using an Alexa blueprint; blueprints have a 'share' button. (Unfortunately, my type of smart home skill is not available as a blueprint).

Any other options ? I am willing do it using the AWS console, CLI or write an API call. I just want to get a shareable link to my skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Beta Test](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/skills-beta-testing-for-alexa-skills.html) feature for that!

1. Go into the [Alexa developer console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask)
2. Then go into your skill
3. Click on the distribution tab
4. Complete all required information and click on Availability
5. Enter the email addresses of the users that are going to test

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Personal experience note: Amazon required me to fill out a 3 page form to register the Alexa skill. Beta testing is on the last page.
I had seen the form earlier, but it asked for intimidating information like my 'company logo', privacy policy URL and 'terms and conditions' document. For this reason, I had not proceeded.

But now I realized that blank icons and fake URLs are accepted, so I have filled it with place holders.
Then I successfully added my friends as beta testers.

Comment: Just so you know, those informations are legally needed the day you want your skill to be certified and published. Blank data will not pass the certification process. It will help users understanding what you're skill will do with their data, ...

Comment: I agree. But skills created through blueprints have a simple 'share this skill with your friend' button, and it simply gives you a URI. High school students and smalltime hobbyists, whose skills are never meant to be published on Amazon, should also have a way to copy paste example code, try it, share it and have fun ! These are precisely the army of future developers who are going to create the next generation Alexa skills.